# concatenate strings with extra characters and symbols in between in matlab

Tags: matlab

Background: I am getting files through `uigetfile`, `'multiselect'` is set "on".

Now: user selectes files.

```
    filename = [FileName(1) FileName(2) ....]
I have filename = 'name1' 'name2'.....
filename(1) = 'name1'
filename(2) = 'name2'
.
.
.
```

How can I make this into `filename = {'name1.m','name2.m',.....}`

How does the concatenation works here ?

["...." represents that the there can be two files, or 4 , basically depends on user selection]

Comment: It's not entirely clear what result you are trying to achieve, do you want a cell array of the filenames such as  fcell = {FileName{1}, FileName{2}}

Comment: @CatsLoveJazz...if you call this {'name1.m','name2.m',.....} a cell array then yes. please note I can arrange the files and even put { and } at the start and end respectively, but I am struggling a bit to insert .m and ' '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is that you want your `filename` string to look exactly like  `{'name1.m','name2.m',.....}`, then try this:

```
files = uigetfile('MultiSelect', 'on');
//the files here will have already the extensions of the files (e.g .m, .jpg, etc.)

s = '{'; //create a string s that starts with a {

for i=1:length(files)

    //to add apostrophes, use ''''. This means one single apostrophe
    s = strcat(s, '''',files(i), '''');

    if i ~= length(files)
       //add a comma if it is not the last file
       s = strcat(s, ','); 
    end


end

//finish off with another }, and check your final string s
s = strcat(s, '}')
```

Comment: Super. the only problem is answer is wrapped in between '   '.

Comment: When you display the filename, matlab automatically shows the apostrophes surrounding the string. But if you use the variable, the surrounding apostrophes are not included inside

Comment: How do you convert a filename to a variable?

Comment: In the example above, s is a string variable. When you display s (by excluding the semi colon in the code), matlab shows the string surrounded by two apostrophes. However, s itself(if you continue using it in the code), does not contain the surrounding apostrophes

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
filename ={ 'name1' 'name2'};

filename = 

'name1'    'name2'

output = cellfun(@(x) {horzcat(x,'.m')},filename);

output = 

'name1.m'    'name2.m'
```

String concatenation in Matlab is much like that of in Java, basically if you have 'a'+'b' this will give you 'ab' in Java, in Matlab, you concatenate it ['a','b'] will give you ['ab'] (like concatenating a Char Array). To do this for all of your file names, you will need to use Matlab's cellfun, which applies the concatenation to each and every one of your file names.

----EDIT----

If you want everything in 1 String (1 x 1 Cell):

```
output = cellfun(@(x) {horzcat(x,'.m, ')},filename); %//Adds the .m comma space to each string in cell
outputAll = {cat(2,output{:})}; %//Merge all cells together
outputOneString = outputAll{1}(1:end-2); %//remove the comma space at the end of the String

outputOneString =

name1.m, name2.m
```

Comment: Thanks. That works fine. but how do you put "," in between files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strcat](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) on the cell array:

```
filenames = {'name1', 'name2', 'name3'};
result = strcat(filenames, '.m')

result = 

    'name1.m'    'name2.m'    'name3.m'
```